# setExposureModeCustom: Duration/ISO values in EXIF data do not match

Tags: ios, avcapturedevice, ios-camera

I'm working on an app that uses various advanced iOS camera controls, e.g. custom exposure settings (duration and ISO). The exposure is locked at custom values using:

```
device.setExposureModeCustom(duration: duration, iso: iso) {
    (timestamp:CMTime) -> Void in
    // ...
}
```

My app is also locking the device gains corresponding to a specific temperature/tint combination.

Everything seemed to work so far. However, when I open the resulting photo files (JPGs in my case) and look at the exposure duration/ISO values that are stored in the EXIF tags, I notice that **there are huge differences between the values that I have specified programmatically and the values that are in the EXIF tags**.

I have tested this with various different exposure duration/ISO combinations. As you can see, in most cases, the error is quite large:

[image: Testing various exposure duration/ISO settings and comparing them with the EXIF data.]

Why is that? Can anyone reproduce/confirm this issue? It seems like a bug on Apple's part.

Photos are captured using AVCapturePhotoOutput's capturePhoto method:

```
self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: captureProcessor)
```

Yes, I double and triple-checked that the exposure mode is set to `.custom` before taking any photos. The code configuring the AVCaptureDevice *is* working properly. You can also see that it is working in the preview, for example, using larger exposure durations or larger ISO values results in a brighter image, as you would expect.

Possibly related:

- [How to accurately set fast shutter speeds (exposure duration) on an AVCaptureDevice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59094770/how-to-accurately-set-fast-shutter-speeds-exposure-duration-on-an-avcapturedev)
- [iOS + AVFoundation. Different photo brightness with the same manual exposure settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511431/ios-avfoundation-different-photo-brightness-with-the-same-manual-exposure-set)

---

My device: iPad Pro (10.5"), iOS 13.2.2

Comment: Try saving the image in HEIC (the default format for iOS devices) and check the status!

Comment: @DakshGargas Great idea! I've tested the settings duration=5ms/iso=1000, duration=50ms/iso=200 and duration=100ms/iso=200. Using the HEIC format did not make any difference. The parameters stored in the EXIF tags suffer from the exact same shifts/offsets as in the corresponding JPG files.

Comment: I have observed the same issue on iPhones, in every captureDevice format and camera combinations. The ISO and exposureDuration values settings in custom mode, are well applied in the iPhone camera. But the EXIF values are (almost) always wrongs. I guess, EXIF values for ISO are legacy based, and can only take photography historical values (32, 40, 64 ...). And the same things seems to happen with exposureDuration, it can only take fractions like 1/40s 1/60s. Even if Apple applies your settings correctly, the EXIF attached with the photo contains legacy values.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem. Make sure the `isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled` property is set to false:

```
let photoSettings: AVCapturePhotoSettings

if self.photoOutput.availablePhotoCodecTypes.contains(.hevc) {
    photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey:  AVVideoCodecType.hevc])
} else {
    photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
}

photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = false
self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: captureProcessor)
```